# Can TeamCity Update TFS work item with build number?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I've got TeamCity set up with continuous integration so that when I check in, a TeamCity build triggers. We use TFS for source control & work management. As part of our internal process, all check ins are associated with a TFS work item.

What I'd like to do, is to get TeamCity to update the work item that was associated to the check in that triggered the CI build, to update the TFS work item with the build number it has triggered. I know I've seen MS Build doing this in the past. Is it possible with TeamCity?

Thanks in advance.